# In Firefox, how to subscribe to RSS feed without "Reader vs Homepage" page?

Tags: google-reader, firefox

Using Firefox 11, though I remember this being true in versions past, as well. Is there any way to tell Firefox to add RSS feeds to Google Reader specifically, rather than to just "Google", so I don't have to go through the "Google Homepage" vs "Google Reader" selection screen every single time?

I could have sworn I'd done this in the past, but I've been away from Reader for awhile and now can't find any instructions for it via Google Search, Mozilla Help, and Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing Better GReader in Firefox:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/better-greader/

- Go to Firefox's Add-ons Manager (Tools > Add-ons) and select "Extensions".
- Find *Better GReader* in the list of extensions and click the *Options* button.
- Click the *Subscribing* tab.
- Check the box for *Auto Add to Reader (Bypass iGoogle Choice)*
- Click OK.

That's it. When you choose to subscribe via Google, it'll go straight to Google Reader.

Comment: Huh, I actually looked at Better GReader, but the page doesn't mention that particular feature at all. In any case, it works like a charm.

Comment: Glad to hear it!